# How do I write a type generic for converting a dot notated object into a nested object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have been losing my mind trying to figure out how to create this generic type, and am starting to convince myself it's just not possible.

What I have is structured data that when fetched, is fetched as a flat object.

```
type TestObjectType = {
    'foo.bar': boolean;
    'foo.baz': string;
    'foo.foo.bar.': string;
    'baz': string;
}
// or 
const testObject = {
    'foo.bar': true,
    'foo.baz': 'some deep value',
    'foo.foo.bar': 'deeper value',
    'baz': 'another baz',
} as const
```

I have a function that successfully expands this object into

```
const expanded = {
    foo: {
        bar: true,
        baz: 'some deep value',
        foo: {
            bar: 'deeper value'
        }
    },
    baz: 'another baz'
}
```

The problem is, I am having to either create a brand new type for the expanded value, leave as `any`, or return the current structure, which is incorrect. My solution, was to create an expander generic that can take the flat object and expand the type out from the keys.

I see a lot of examples of going the opposite direction, and have an implementation of a nested object to flat object type, but nothing going the other direction (which does concern me, making me feel it isn't possible)

---

I have a type that almost works, the problem is, it is intersecting the keys instead of unioning the keys...

```
type ExpandedObject<T extends Record<string, any>, Del extends string = '.'> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends `${infer First}${Del}${infer Rest}`
        ? First : K]: K extends `${infer First}${Del}${infer Rest}`
        ? ExpandedObject<{[R in Rest]: T[K]}> : T[K]
}
```

```
foo: ExpandedObject<{bar: boolean}, "."> | ExpandedObject<{baz: string}, "."> | ExpandedObject<{"foo.bar.": string}, ".">
```

---

I have also tried another approach of converting the keys using...

```
type StringToNestedObject<S extends string, V> = S extends `${infer T}.${infer U}`
    ? {[Key in T]: StringToNestedObject<U, V>}
    : {[Key in S]: V};



type ExpandedObject<T extends Record<string, any>> = keyof T extends string ? StringToNestedObject<keyof T, string> : never
```

This runs into the same intersection problem, however, if I manually union the parts, it would work.

```
const foobar: StringToNestedObject<'foo.bar', boolean> & StringToNestedObject<'foo.baz', string> & StringToNestedObject<'bar', boolean> = {} as any;

foobar.foo.bar // boolean;
foobar.foo.baz // string;
```

---

Comment: I'm going to assume that the trailing period in `foo.foo.bar.` is a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have some utility types to split/join strings, it'll make things a lot easier:

```
type Split<S extends string, Sep extends string = "", R extends string[] = []> =
    S extends ""
        ? R
        : S extends `${infer A}${Sep}${infer B}`
            ? Split<B, Sep, [...R, A]>
            : [...R, S];

type Join<S extends string[], Sep extends string = "", R extends string = ""> =
    S["length"] extends 0
        ? R
        : S extends [infer A extends string, ...infer B extends string[]]
            ? Join<B, Sep, `${R}${R extends "" ? "" : Sep}${A}`>
            : R;
```

then you can create an `Unflatten` type:

```
type Unflatten<T> = T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T & string as Split<K, ".">[0]]: [K] extends [`${string}.${string}`]
        ? Unflatten<{
            [P in Split<K, "."> extends [any, ...infer Rest extends string[]] ? Join<Rest, "."> : never]: T[`${Split<K, ".">[0]}.${P}` & keyof T]
          }>
        : T[K];
} : T;
```

Mapping over the first layer by splitting the keys and getting the first element, we can check if `K` (the key) has a child property. Then, if it does, we can unflatten all of its subproperties. If it doesn't have a child property, we leave it as-is.

This is the result using your example `TestObjectType`:

```
// type T = Unflatten<TestObjectType>
type T = {
    foo: {
        foo: {
            bar: string;
        };
        baz: string;
        bar: boolean;
    };
    baz: string;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwDyAjAVhAxsG5oF4oBvAKCnKgCIAzAe1oDoUBDAJ0oC4oV6AbCZgDsA3GQo16TZgC9OURKwCWggOaiKVOoy1T2XBcrVjyLafuBLVogL6iSoSFADKYXouAAeJ1AgAPYBCCACbw8haGADTOEGA+-oEhYZYqUISUlFEASnEBwaEGqgDaALqpUCUAfKnGzjkJoek1GgD8UJlNFFzefrmJAAYAJETK1BCsUACC1kNOMdPDgqPjAELWfR0a5K0ubp7LUbNgUYUMp5lRE8UVG5tcJ2cHxXYO0ABStMpedXlJhiUHMW+iQKKTSGTaQPy4VUZXSVXwNSchUo-FUwAAFpRSj16lAAAw3VrtTadWo4n6FEZjSaQ36qKKnBhUla0kElYo3FpQd6ffbRI5QQZETLzbLkxLpKCtSVdOZDKZ9a4kklcTLPPBQACqi14zGAuQ8MHhsFptHQWGAUuINUKAGkoMooABrCAgWjUE0AMjpKWYoR27g8tqilAYlAqhTxxWKd1t2PiFKFIOsDCGyb6HOVVu11F1+sCHlIWY0hQACg7BM5XIHg1Qw1VxaFCkIQAzTsy2ghLY2feyrTzBB5Ml2Q-WoFxBBAAG5jGOwQpCgOeWuh8OR4opoaltZQb0ut0emCZ4vWJXKrgwO1PEjWcewdWOGBlHN5g1wRCoDDYXCQCqiAD0-4UAAes0QA)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been puzzling over this for the last 3 days off and on as it keeps coming up as an issue and I've just been working around it. I found it MUCH easier to flatten the type.